# the method addannotatedclass class is undefined for the type configuration (Hibernate )

Tags: java, hibernate

I would appreciate some help with this, I got a basic Hibernate configuration nearly completed, but I keep getting the following error:

> The method addannotatedclass class is undefined for the type configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LocalVariableDeclarationStatement - The method addAnnotatedClass() is undefined for the type Configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802654/localvariabledeclarationstatement-the-method-addannotatedclass-is-undefined)

Comment: lack of dependencies..post your code and dependencies...also refer the link by @waka

Comment: please include your configuration